# Azure b2c tenant and GitHub connect. Given Name and Surname not displaying

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Azure b2c tenant and GitHub connect. Given Name and Surname not displaying for SignIn user flow,Is there any way to debug this from azure portal side or any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix it in production, you can setup [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-guide-troubleshooting-custom). also, Did you have a look at?

[**`Troubleshoot Azure AD B2C custom policies and Identity Experience Framework`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-guide-troubleshooting-custom)